# negative values in highcharts stacked column chart

Tags: highcharts

The issue is about the stacked column chart with negative values. Please refer the example in http://jsfiddle.net/n88dF/1/. Please pay attention to the 1st stacked column’s sequence. It is different from others. Can I keep the sequence the same as others?

```
series: [{
            name: 'A',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: '0'
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: '0'
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            data: [-3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: '0'
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            data: [-5, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: '0'
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related with fact that you have negative values, which are below 0 and it is defaulty Highcharts behaviour. Only what you can do is preprocess data.